# Редактирование html кода страницы Wordpress, которая подгрузилась через шорткод WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

$username. Не могу найти, как поменять html код на странице, связанные с WooCommerce. К примеру, текст на thup после оформления заказа. Он дефолтный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лазил на хостинге в поисках нужного php файла (в php я не силён), там всё что я нашел это все та же подгрузка контента через

> do_action

Как поменять контент не понятно.
Единственное, что пришло мне в голову - это менять содержимое при помощи JS, но данное решение само по себе глупо. Буду очень признателен за любой толчок в нужном направлении. Спасибо.

Comment: Это thankyou.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это шаблон thankyou.php WooCommerce-плагина.

Вариант 1. Использовать стандартные хуки из шаблона: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/thankyou.php

Вариант 2. Создать в теме файл woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php и там можете переопределять его как вам угодно.